# Add line breaks inside property to be displayed within <p> tags in the template angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a property errorMessage declared in my ts component. I need to store a string within this that contains multiple lines that need to be separated by a line. '\n' doesn't seem to work with this. Please suggest the way to do this.

In ts component:

```
this.errorMessage = 'An error has been encountered. \nDetails:\n' + errorString;
```

In html template:

```
<p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the one trick here as you can use **[innerHTML]** attribute to show you html that is inside your **errorMessage**

You have to modify your code in component like

```
this.errorMessage = 'An error has been encountered. <br>Details:' + errorString;
```

And in your template you can render you above message by using above attribute like

```
<p [innerHTML]="errorMessage"></p>
```

The above code will render your errorMessage as a HTML not a string so line break will also rendered

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution would be to just use **innerHTML** instead.

**Change this:**

```
this.errorMessage = 'An error has been encountered. \nDetails:\n' + errorString;

<p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
```

**To this:**

```
this.errorMessage = 'An error has been encountered. <br>Details:<br>' + errorString;

<p [innerHTML]="errorMessage"></p>
```

However there are some caveats to this solution. You can find more about it here
https://angular.io/guide/security

Comment: Thanks for the answer.